# Oracle 11g and SQL TOP query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

While using `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM SOMETABLE` gives me an error

*ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected*

I am using Oracle 11g . I am aware of using `rownum` for doing the same thing but just wondering SQL TOP usage is not at all supported in Oracle ? Anything need to do extra to make SQL TOP working in Oracle ??

Comment: Yup... TOP is no go. But I think Uncle Google would have told you that too...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oracle does not support `TOP`. Use `ROWNUM`

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9de39/2)

Comment: Thanks for giving info about SQLFiddle :) :)

Comment: @Oracle: SQL was intended to be a standard. Act like it is one!

Answer (score 2):

No, Oracle does not support `TOP`.

As you point out, the best approach is to use `rownum`. Another option is the analytical function [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The `rownum` keyword, while it gets you the said no. of records, does so only after applying the `order by` clause if you have one.

So if the SQL server query is as below, it will give you 10 most recently created records.

```
Select TOP 10 * from mytable order by created_date desc
```

But to fit Oracle, when you write this, it gets you the 10 records (that may not be the most recent ones) and arranges them in descending order, which is not what you wanted.

```
Select * from mytable where rownum < 10 order by created_date desc
```

So writing with an additional select like this would help:

```
SELECT * FROM (Select * from mytable order by created_date desc) where rownum < 10
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL TOP does NOT work for Oracle.

Comment: -1 : This isn't helpful... If this is to be ***helpful*** why not supply the correct method? Such as **how to use** `rownum` or `ROW_NUMBER()` for this example?

Comment: @Dems, it says it is already aware of rownum and he asked "if is not at all supporte in Oracle". If I had explained about rownum, there may be someone who could have also downvoted because of that. Don't really understand why downvoting if I answered its question.